# Retrieve a select count(*) in Oracle inside a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, rowcount

I need to retrieve the number of rows in a SELECT COUNT(*) statement that is inside a cursor (in Oracle).

The following code should explain it clearly:

```
PROCEDURE Save(CF_CURSOR OUT "VPA"."CF_#Runtime".CF_CURSOR_TYPE) AS
    V_CF_CURSOR "VPA"."CF_#Runtime".CF_CURSOR_TYPE;
    CF_ROWCOUNT NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        OPEN V_CF_CURSOR FOR
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CF_ROWCOUNT FROM (
            SELECT * FROM "VPA"."Employee" -- returns 1 row
        ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
        IF(CF_ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN
            -- DO SOMETHING BUT NEVER GOES HERE
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
    CF_CURSOR := V_CF_CURSOR;
    END;
```

Here, the value of CF_ROWCOUNT is never set. If I remove the cursor, everything works as expected. I have tried to use SQL%ROWCOUNT, but it does not work either.
And, I cannot remove the cursor...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly it's not going to work as your syntax is incorrect. Secondly when you write _"I have tried to use SQL%ROWCOUNT, but it does not work either"_ what doesn't work? Did you get error messages? What did you run? Lastly, are you simply trying to get a count or do you also want to use the data in employee?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing a `FETCH` on the cursor before you can get a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried opening the cursor - which does a COUNT(*), then fetching that into the CF_ROWCOUNT variable instead of doing it as an INTO within the ref-cursor statement.

For example:

```
OPEN V_CF_CURSOR FOR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "VPA"."Employee"; -- returns 1 row
FETCH V_CF_CURSOR INTO CF_ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. 
The main issue is that this code is auto-generated and I don't have full control on what gets generated. Your solution works. But I have decided to remove the cursor (and that works), because I only need to retrieve the number of rows fetched with the select statement and nothing else.